# Undefined offset: 1

Tags: offsets

I get an  **Undefined offset: 1** message from this query below.
Do not understand why I get it. The echo results in correct data.

```
echo $url_slug ;
$Exploded_slug = explode($user->ID.'--',$url_slug);
print_r($Exploded_slug );
```

$url_slug result: 4--106

print_r($Exploded_slug ) result: Array ( [0] => 4--106 )

```
$query = "SELECT comments FROM wp_rdp_winners WHERE id = $Exploded_slug[1]";
$comments = $wpdb->get_var($query);
```

The above query is empty. ID 4 has no comments and does not exist in table. If this means that the ID = 4 has not a comments field, then how can I skip this whit an if statement?

Comment: Why do you use $Exploded_slug[1] instead of $Exploded_slug[0] in your query? From what I can tell in your code it is empty. Also it is preferred to use lower case for regular variables like yours, so I'd also change $Exploded_slug to $exploded_slug.

Comment: You're right! Oeps. Blind since today. But you open my eyes. Thanks

Comment: Alright, gonna put it into a better formatted answer then.

Comment: ok. then I can give you a positive feedback

Comment: Now that I've posted my answer and thought more about what you're trying to achieve I got a bit confused xD You sure it works right when you just replace 1 with 0? Because then you'd get `WHERE id = '4--106'` which is not only the same as `WHERE id = $url_slug` but also probably wouldn't work the way you want it... Can you provide an example of the url?

Comment: If it works then don't bother, of course, since I can't check the rest of your code I could be wrong with my assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$Exploded_slug[1]` is empty, don't forget that arrays are 0-based. So you need to change your query. Also it is preferred to use lower case for regular variables like yours, so I'd also change $Exploded_slug to $exploded_slug.

Here's the code:

```
$exploded_slug = explode($user->ID.'--', $url_slug);
$query = "SELECT comments FROM wp_rdp_winners WHERE id = $exploded_slug[0]";
$comments = $wpdb->get_var($query);
```

Actually I don't see the point of making an array here, why not simply concatenate? Using explode here doesn't make much sense anyway, you might want to read [this simple explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) of this function with an example. So instead try this:

```
$exploded_slug = $user->ID . '--' . $url_slug;
$query = "SELECT comments FROM wp_rdp_winners WHERE id = $exploded_slug";
$comments = $wpdb->get_var($query);
```

But if you're going to add more elements to the `$exploded_slug` later then use the first variant. But declare the $exploded_slug variable differently, maybe like so:

```
$exploded_slug = array($user->ID . '--' . $url_slug);
```